# Database table structure for storing SSO information for FB or Google+

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, single-sign-on, google-oauth

I have a web application that I would like to add single sign on capability using user's Facebook or Google+/Google App account.

I have a `USERS` table that stores users login information.  All users are required to have a record in this table no matter if they signed up using FB or Google+.

I am trying to figure out the information that I need to store in the database in order to link `USERS` table records to FB or Google information.

Facebook [documentation states](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#token):

> the app should store the token in a database along with the `user_id`
>   to identify it.

So should I create a table called `SSO_LOOKUP` with following columns:

- USER_ID // user's id that links to my `USER` table
- PROVIDER_ID // user's FB or Google account id
- PROVIDER_TYPE // indicates if it is Google, FB, Twitter, etc.
- ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 4):

For SSO login definitely you need to have your user_id and some basic details which allow you to connect to FB or google

- **provider**: "it will be either FB or Google or anything in future"
- **token**: "This token we receive from FB and Google. In case of FB it
  expires after 3 months or so where as it does not expire for google
  as per my knowledge"
- **token_expired**:" As In FB token expires after a time so you can have
  this flag in place if you need to refresh it after that duration"
- **user_id**: "This is your User id:
- **uniqueid**: "This is the Unique ID which you will get from FB and Google.
  That helps to identify your user in FB/Google"

These are the minimum fields you can add and these will even help you to scale your app. In the sense if you want to *pull or push* data from google and FB at that time Access_token and unique_id will help you.

Also incase you want to see some publish source then you can see some of the code on github e.g.
[django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/migrations/0001_initial.py#L23)

For some details you can refer [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver) and [Google OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking all you really need to store is the `Refresh Token` and some kind of flag type identifier that tells you if its a Facebook or Google Refresh Token.   Then you can query the API for what ever information you need. Storing the User Id would be a good idea becouse if they logout then reauth you will still know who it is even though the refresh token has changed.    anything else is kind of over kill really as you will be getting that information back from the API anyway when you make your calls.

You could if you want store there Name and most recent picture that might be nice to display before you have fetched there information. Then update any changes to your data after you access the API for the first time.  But its basically up to you how you want to design things, and what kind of application we are talking about here.